# Database driven radio button ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to update my conditions table with the radio button's value on and off

Here is the view

```
= form_tag('/admin/save',:action => 'update') do    
 = radio_button_tag("#{cols}_#{id}",1,checked = eval(check), options = {}) 
 = radio_button_tag("#{cols}_#{id}",0,checked = eval(negcheck), options = {})
 = submit_tag
```

Here is the controller

```
def updateCondition
    params.each do |keys , value|
      key ="#{keys}"
      condition = key.split("_")[0]
      hospitalid =key.split("_")[1]
      if condition == "utf8" || condition == "authenticity" || condition == "commit"
        next        
      end
      Condition.find(hospitalid).update(:"#{condition}" =>  params["#{condition}_#{hospitalid}"])
    end
    render nothing: true
  end
```

Params are :

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"",
 "abc_10000"=>"1",
 "commit"=>"Save changes",
 "def_10000"=>"1",


 }
```

Here is my question :

1) Why params is not showing  all my radio button values ?
2) Any way to handle utf8, authentication_token, commit other than if statement ?

Comment: Can you please add to your question the rendered html generated by the two radio buttons?

Answer (score 0):

This may be why params not showing:

This looks strange to me: `checked = eval(check)` should it be `checked: eval(check)` or `checked == eval(check)`

Why are you setting `options = {}`? I think options should be passed in as a hash or not passed in at all.

Regarding #2,

```
if condition == "utf8" || condition == "authenticity" || condition == "commit"
  next        
end
Condition.find(hospitalid).update(:"#{condition}" =>  params["#{condition}_#{hospitalid}"])
```

You could extract that into a separate function:

```
def condition_valid?
  condition == "utf8" || condition == "authenticity" || condition == "commit"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking two questions here which is bad protocol for SO.  I'll answer the second one.

Rather than try to filter out the parameters you don't want, which is very fragile, you could send through all the things you are trying to process, grouped into a single param.  Eg, in your form, change the radio buttons to

```
= form_tag('/admin/save',:action => 'update') do    
 = radio_button_tag("conditions[#{id}][#{cols}]"}",1,checked = eval(check), options = {})  
 = radio_button_tag("conditions[#{id}][#{cols}]"}",0,checked = eval(negcheck), options = {})
 = submit_tag
```

this will give you params like

```
 {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"",
 :conditions => {1000 => {:abc => 1, :def => 1}}, 
 "commit"=>"Save changes"
 }
```

See how they are organised and separated?  This means you don't have to muck about splitting them up again.

Now your controller code could be:

```
def updateCondition
  params[:conditions].each do |id , attributes|
    if condition = Condition.find_by_id(id)
      condition.update_attributes(attributes)
    end
  end
  render nothing: true
end
```

Note:  you don't say what the value of "cols" is when you are building the form so i'm having to guess a bit.  I think i just copied the way you are using it but shuffled it around a bit.  There is almost certainly a cleaner way to build the form too.